# Access SQL Query from another Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a little problem with a piece of SQL code. I have a table *Paiements_17_18* and I would like to create a single-line query that calculates:

- the total of the *Amount* field,
- the first date of *Date_Regulation* field,
- the last date of *Date_Regulation* field,
- the distinct values of *N_Facture* field.

All this from a sub request of the style `SELECT TOP n FROM ....`

I tried this:

```
SELECT Sum(P.Montant) AS TotalMontant, 
       First(P.Date_Regulation) AS PremièreDate, 
       Last(P.Date_Regulation) AS DernièreDate, 
       First(P.N_Facture) AS PremièreFacture, 
       Last(P.N_Facture) AS DernièreFacture, 
       (SELECT Count(N_Facture) 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT N_Facture FROM Paiements_17_18)) AS NombreFactures

FROM (SELECT TOP 5 Paiements_17_18.* 
      FROM Paiements_17_18 
      ORDER BY Paiements_17_18.ID_Paiement DESC) AS P;
```

But I get an error of "P"

> (The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or
>   query" P" . Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled
>   correctly)

Can you help me please?

Comment: If you remove the 2 lines for generating NombreFactures, do you get error?

Comment: From my sample data following your logic, I cannot reproduce error. By looking at syntax I cannot see why the error is raised. Make sure this exact query is generating that error. Possibly your actual did not include table alias, `P`.

Comment: @kc2018; Yes when i remove the line generating NombreFactures, there is no more error !!

Comment: @Parfait; what do you mean by I didn't Include the table's alias P

Comment: I am saying in your actual query, you may hve missed the `P` at end even though here it is posted. Very odd! I tested that `SELECT Count(...) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ...)` without an issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 lines on generating the NombreFacture field is causing the error:

```
(SELECT Count(N_Facture) 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT N_Facture FROM Paiements_17_18)) AS 
NombreFactures
```

Replaced the two lines. See below.

```
SELECT Sum(P.Montant) AS TotalMontant, 
       First(P.Date_Regulation) AS PremièreDate, 
       Last(P.Date_Regulation) AS DernièreDate, 
       First(P.N_Facture) AS PremièreFacture, 
       Last(P.N_Facture) AS DernièreFacture, 
       (SELECT Count(n.N_Facture_distinct) 
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT N_Facture as N_facture_distinct FROM Paiements_17_18 ) AS n) 
        AS NombreFacture 
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 Paiements_17_18.* 
      FROM Paiements_17_18 
      ORDER BY Paiements_17_18.ID_Paiement DESC) AS P;
```

Comment: @kc2018; I got an error "access circular reference caused by alias [N_Facture] in query definition's SELECT list"    :(

Comment: I have changed the variable name from N_facture to N_facture_distinct

Comment: @HoucineAdsens ... please provide sample data of *Paiments_17_18*, so we can fully reproduce issue.

Comment: @kc2018; Finally it works, thank you thank you very very much, but I have another question if you allow me. I want to calculate The Destinct [N_Facture] from P. not from the Table!   for exemple if i Have SELECT TOP 5, i want just count destinct [N_Facture] of the 5 first records. Not from all the table

Comment: @HoucineAdsens; Try count(distinct P.N_Facture) instead of the 2 lines of subquery.

Comment: @kc2018; I feel we are realy close; your line of code is for SQL Server, But i'm working on Access Sql !!

Comment: @kc2018; (SELECT COUNT(N_Facture) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT N_Facture FROM P)) As NombreFactures ??

Comment: @HoucineAdsens; how about replacing the reference to Paiement_17_18 in the inner query to "(SELECT Top 5 N_Facture from Paiement_17_18 ORDER BY Paiements_17_18.ID_Paiement DESC) AS t".  Not pretty but should work.  I wanted to test the syntax but I don't have MS Access environment.